# html file wont read onclick attribute as a string

Tags: javascript, html

I am really new to coding and I am following this video tutorial to make a website that displays someone's age in days depending on the prompt input. I am trying to link an `onclick` attribut to an HTML button that will link to my js function. the problem is that the `onclick` attribute will not read the js function as a string; thus, not functioning properly. I have tried to google the solution for almost an hour now, but I have not found anything that works. Please help. EDIT: I was told to add parentheses and it still did not work.

html code:

```html
<div class="container1">
  <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days</h2>
  <div class="flexboxcontainer1">
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageindays()">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexboxcontainer1">
    <div id="flexboxresult"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="project1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

js code:

```js
function ageindays() {
  var birthyear = prompt("What year were you born.. Good friend?");
}
```

Comment: You need to invoke it with parentheses.

Comment: when I added the parentheses, it still did not work.

Comment: see if you js file is loaded, maybe just add your function without any src then move it into a js file and reverence properly

Comment: OMG it worked!! thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it with `()`. So, it will be `onclick="ageindays()"`

```js
function ageindays() {
    var birthyear = prompt("What year were you born.. Good friend?");
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
    <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days</h2>
    <div class="flexboxcontainer1">
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageindays()">Click Me</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexboxcontainer1">
        <div id="flexboxresult"></div>
    </div>
</div>    
<script src="project1.js"></script>
```